# Is it possible to set up a base project for use across multiple ASP.NET MVC projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

My team lead handed this one to me, and I'm a bit stumped. We have just started using ASP.NET MVC for web development in our shop, and there are common design and functionality that we would like to be able to use across multiple sites.

So far, I have looked at creating a custom template with the common elements, but the downside to that is that updates to the template (as far as I can tell) do not automatically get pushed to projects created using that template. As having changes automatically update to the consuming projects is a requirement, custom templates won't work for me.

My question is, is it possible to set up a base project for use across multiple ASP.NET MVC projects, where updates to the base get propogated to the consuming projects? If you have any experience in this field, I would certainly appreciate some direction. My apologies if this question seems elementary to you, but this is my first real foray into ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that the best method for sharing resources between disparate projects is to create your own Nuget packages. These can contain anything from a class library with reusable classes, enums, extension methods, etc. to entire web applications complete with controllers, views, JavaScript, CSS, etc. The scope is entirely up to how much commonality you can abstract from your projects. You can then set up your own private Nuget repository to hold these so you don't have to publish them to the whole world. (Although, if you do create something that would benefit others as well, by all means do share on the official Nuget repo.)

Setting everything up is pretty trivial. I learned how to create Nuget packages and set up a private repo in a day. Here's some resources to get you started:

1. [Official Nuget documentation for creating and deploying packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)
2. [Using the Package Explorer application to create packages via a GUI](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages)
3. [Official Nuspec (the package manifest file) reference.](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference)
4. [Hosting your own Nuget feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)
5. [Alternate method for creating your own repository with SymbolSource integration](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2011-04-22/Set_up_your_own_NuGet_gallery_with_SymbolSource)

[SymbolSource](http://www.symbolsource.org/) also offers private repos, remotely hosted on their servers, gratis. Some enterprise environments may not like having their code "in the cloud", but if you can get by with it, this is by far the easiest way to get going.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, the company I work for has found that whilst there are common design and functionality elements across our project, the uncommon elements can be too broad which outweighs then need to have some form of base project. Using custom project templates also become a maintenance nightmare so avoid those.

Instead we've opted to document how a project should be setup for particular designs and it's up to the Team Lead to follow which bits are needed for the particular project they are working on.

If there a functional overlaps we've considered (but not actually yet done) creating a common library(s) that has they're own development lifecyle, and then setup our own [NuGet Server](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) for distribution of the common library to your other projects. We haven't done this yet mainly because again the differences between projects we have worked tend to be large enough for this not be warranted.

But from the sound of what you're describing, NuGet packages or something similar could be the way to go in your case.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think there's a way to set up a base project that everything else inherits from, you could quite easily set up a common library project that all others reference. It could include base classes for all the common things you'll be using (eg `ControllerBase`).

This way, updating the library project will allow new functionality to be added to all other projects. You could configure templates so that the common base classes are used by default when adding new elements.

Depending on how you reference the common library (compiled dll/linked project reference) you either get a stable link to a specific version or instant updates across all projects. I'd personally prefer to reference the common dll rather than the project, since this allows `project A` to be using an older version than `project B`. Updating A to the new version is trivial, but it gives you a level of separation so that if `B` requires breaking changes, you don't have to waste resources to keep `A` working.

Another added bonus is that checking out an old version from source control would still be guaranteed to work as it would be tied to the version of the library in use at the time it was created.